# Search Ruby hash for value?

Tags: ruby

Trying to search through a hash for a value, no methods I have tried previously have worked.

```
def input
  @search_term = STDIN.gets.chomp
end

def execute
  @reader.searchKey(@search_term).each{|b| puts b}
end

def searchKey(search_term)
  puts books_catalogue.has_value?(search_term)
end
```

Comment: post the error you get. Also explain in detail what all you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, but this code snippet too vague to understand.

Comment: do you want to get each key of the hash that has the value passed as argument ? If so, just take a look at my answer, else, could you add some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {foo: 'val', bar: 'other_val', bak: 'val'}
selected_hash = hash.select { |k,v| v == 'val' } # => {foo: 'val', bak: 'val'}
selected_hash.keys # => [:foo, :bak]
```

So the method looks like:

```
def search_key(value)
  @hash.select { |k, v| v == value }.keys
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}
value_to_search_for = 2
hash.select {|_,value| value == value_to_search_for}
# output is {b: 2, c: 2}
```